# Why is '\\' considered int?

Tags: c

When tried to compare a char* and '\' to see if they are the same, I just used character == '\', but it give me this warning message and when I ran it I got segmentation fault:11. Snippets follows.

```
int strcompare(char *string1, char *string2) {
  int i = 0;
  while(string1[i] != 0 & string2[i] != 0) {
    if (string1[i] != string2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return true;
}


int special_character_is_in_pattern(char *pattern) {
  int i = 0;
  while(i<32) {
    char *character = &pattern[i];
    //int is_in = is_in_list(character, special_character_list);
    return (strcompare(character, ".")|strcompare(character,"+")|strcompare(character,"?")|character == '\\') ? true : i++;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The error message was like this:

```
a.c:39:102: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')
    return (strcompare(character, ".")|strcompare(character,"+")|strcompare(character,"?")|character == '\\') ? true : i++;
                                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
a.c:50:49: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'char *' [-Wint-conversion]
  printf("%d\n",special_character_is_in_pattern('\\'));
```

Need some help, thanks

Comment: `'x'` is an integer value too. The character represented by `'\\'` is merely a single \.

Comment: `... "?")| *character == '\\') ? true : i++;` character is a pointer varable, not a character.

Comment: After I used *character there's not warning! Thanks :), but the thing is it returned 0 which is false, when i executed this line:   printf("%d\n",special_character_is_in_pattern("\\"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"?"` is a string literal.

`'?'` is a character literal.

`"\\"` is a string literal.

`'\\'` is a character literal.

And character literals have type `int` and not `char` in C.

Comment: but since character is a char* how do I compare it with a string literal? do i use character=="\\"?

Comment: @OKthen `character` is a `char *` in your source code, if you want to compare a single character you have to dereference `character`. Also note that `|` is the bitwise OR operator; `||` is the logical OR operator,

Comment: After I used *character there's not warning! Thanks :), but the thing is it returned 0 which is false, when i executed this line:   printf("%d\n",special_character_is_in_pattern("\\")); Also I have changed | to || as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you pass '\\' instead of "\\" special_character_is_in_pattern